# Bug in c++ program during a simple loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

I'm trying to solve this problem as few lines of code as possible.

problem statement:
someone managed to say hello if several letters can be deleted from the typed word so that it resulted in the word "hello"... I'm testing if he could or not

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    char c;
    int i=0; 
    while(i!=5 && (cin>>c) && c!='\n'){
        if(c=="hello"[i])
            i++;
    }
    cout<<((i==5)?"YES":"NO");
}
```

There's a bug when it should print "NO". The program waits for more input. I think the loop doesn't finish until `i==5` but it never finishes when `c=='\n'`.

Comment: i += (c=="hello"[i]) makes the assumption that true == 1. This is not necessarily so. do  i += ((c=="hello"[i])?1:0)

Comment: Actually assume true is a 1 is ok:  The C++ standard §4.7/4  says: "If the source type is bool, the value false is converted to zero and the value true is converted to one."   (Ugly, but legal)

Comment: _"plz "_ Could you please explain to some more extend, what your question has to do with the german abbreviation for _postal code_

Comment: This is a great example of not to put everything on one line or fewest lines as possible.  Making it more readable and using more lines would allow you to use a debugger and inspect your code easier.  There is really no reason to put everything on one line, as whitespace is negligible in compile time and absolutely does not effect execution time.

Comment: changed the loop .. check it please , still the same problem

Comment: I think the problem is with my compiler because I submitted on Codeforces and got AC

Comment: @m.elbarbary _"I think the problem is with my compiler ..."_ That's very unlikely, unless you've got an ancient (pre-standard) one like Turbo-C++.

Comment: YES, you're right ..  I think it's because the Test case on Codeforces ends with EOF not \n like I'm testing it !

Comment: A missing trailing NL should not matter. Assuming you have not found the embedded "Hello" yet, the code will consume the EOF and try another read which will fail causing (cin>>c) to be false.  This will terminate the loop and your program will correctly print NO.   If, on the other hand you do find "Hello" the I != 5 check will fail -- terminating the loop and giving you a "YES"

Answer (score 2):

Before you pack your program to minimize the LOC (and I assume that you have a really good reason to care about this because otherwise it is a foolish thing to do)  make it right!

Try putting the i != 5 test BEFORE the cin >>c test.  Otherwise you read one extra character when you do get a "hello"

Edit: Just to be clear, the code in the question has now been modified to incorporate this suggestion.

Comment: I changed the loop, check it .. It still the same problem

Comment: I think the problem is with my compiler because I submitted on Codeforces and got AC

Comment: I think it's  because the Test case on Codeforces ends with EOF not \n

Answer (score 0):

You have a while loop there

```
while(i!=5 && (cin>>c) && c!='\n')
{ ... }
```

...which you can rewrite for easier debugging. In general, instead of any loop...

```
while (X)
{ Y }
```

...you can also write...

```
while (true)
{
    if (!X) break;
    Y
}
```

For your loop, that would be this code:

```
while (true)
{
    if (!(i!=5 && (cin>>c) && c!='\n'))
        break;
    ...
}
```

Now, I assume you are aware of the short circuit evaluation of the logical AND operator. If not, search the web for that term! With that knowledge, you can rewrite your loop like this:

```
while (true)
{
    if (!(i!=5))
        break;
    if (!(cin>>c))
        break;
    if (!(c!='\n'))
        break;
    ...
}
```

Of course, you can still simplify a few double negations there, but the idea should be clear. This change now allows you to e.g. step through this in a debugger to evaluate each loop exit condition separately. This is important, because the second loop condition also has side effects! In addition, you could e.g. add some debug output that tells you the reason why the loop was exited. Further, for the check that has side effects, you can inspect the intermediate state (or output the state, if you prefer that way), which will give you further insight on the issue.

Lastly, all `>>` operators on `istreams` by default skip whitespace, which includes spaces, tabs and newlines, so your last check will never cause the loop to exit. You can tell the stream to not skip whitespace though, if that's what you want. How to do that should be really simple to find out using another websearch. ;)